Inference speed for tflite fp16 converted model is slow on intel core i5 cpu
I converted an existing tensorflow efficient net model built on tensorflow version 2.3.1 to a tflite fp16 version to reduce its size. I want to run it on CPU and use in my API. But while testing I found out that the inference speed is very slow.
Normally it takes around 0.6sec. But after conversion it takes around 74sec. I also tried using xnnpack delegate but it still isn't improving. Need guidance.
Following is the code used for conversion:
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("modelfile.h5")

print("Running model quantization...")
# Convert the model to TensorFlow Lite format with FP16 quantization
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS]
converter.experimental_new_converter = True
converter.target_spec.supported_types = [tf.float16]

# Perform the conversion
tflite_model_fp16 = converter.convert()

# Save the quantized model
with open('modelfile-fp16.tflite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model_fp16)

And this is the code used for loading model:
# Manually load the XNNPACK delegate
xnnpack_delegate = tf.lite.experimental.load_delegate('./tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/lite/libtensorflowlite.so')
# Load the TFLite model and allocate tensors (done once)
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="modelfile-fp16.tflite", experimental_delegates=[xnnpack_delegate])
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output details (done once)
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

Also I am using this inside docker container only because I had environment setup in it no other reason.
